# Is it OK to use the instance variables created for auto-synthesized properties?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Currently I can write a class like this:

```
@interface Foo
@property(assign) float bar;
@end

@implementation Foo

- (void) someMethod
{
    _bar = 4;
}

@end
```

It’s convenient that I can leave out the `@synthesize` boilerplate list, and if I can get used to the underscore notation, I get the nice readable rule that everything named `_foo` is an instance variable. Is it OK to use the auto-generated instance variables like this? I mean, maybe they’re supposed to be invisible even to the class author?

Comment: you really should be referring to "`self.bar`" and not directly accessing "`_bar`" from anything other than the init method.

Comment: Why? I understand the difference between accessors and plain instance variables and I don’t see why I should go through the accessor all the time. Encapsulation is not a concern here, since we’re talking about the code that implements the class itself.

Comment: In the case of the float I don't think it matters, but for object types I think you need to use the accessor method. Only because you don't want to bypass the retain/release code that is inserted in the property setter. I'm sure somebody will correct me if I'm totally wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely OK to use these variables.

Dropping the `@synthesize` requirement altogether was a convenience: the `@synthesize xyz` is now inserted implicitly - that is the only difference. Designers of the compiler reasoned that since they can unambiguously identify situations when you want to synthesize accessors vs. situations when you provide custom implementations, it is reasonable to stop asking you for an explicit `@synthesize`.

Comment: Just a note: I think that `@synthesize xyz` is still the same as `@synthesize xyz = xyz` (without the underscore), for compatibility with code created by older Xcode versions. Omitting `@synthesize` is the same as `@synthesize xyz = _xyz` (with underscore).

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much, you are absolutely right. I guess I should stop answering questions so early in the morning :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it OK to use the instance variables created for auto-synthesized properties?

Absolutely

> It’s convenient that I can leave out the @synthesize boilerplate list, and if I can get used to the underscore notation, I get the nice readable rule that everything named _foo is an instance variable.

Of course, you also have the ability to specify a name using `@synthesize foo = f00;`.

> Is it OK to use the auto-generated instance variables like this? I mean, aren’t they supposed to be invisible even to the class author?

Nope. It is *necessary* for them to be internally accessible. That's less frequent if you are using ARC, but the common case where you would access them directly is initialization and destruction (cases where the accessor methods should not be used).